# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos, apache2

In my application url after ? i cant able to access the full URL
Example : `www.examle.com/test.php?id=3`
Normally we can get value like

```
$_GET['id'] = 3;
```

But in my app its not working

So i print the $_SERVER values. My output is

```
[UNIQUE_ID] => YjrrveqpEeuu1FcU9vhhAAAAAAQ
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 122.179.51.122, 64.252.100.210
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 443
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com
    [HTTP_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID] => Root=1-623aebbd-28269a532256d99658b3dceb
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Amazon CloudFront
    [HTTP_X_AMZ_CF_ID] => vQJWRlfiiA4QWME7ScshqZmO4aR1nPvGjUKluZOfRK478BtFcIJ30w==
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [HTTP_VIA] => 2.0 3d029316ef030de84eb214747e947124.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => none
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "Windows"
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.example.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 172.31.67.87
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 172.31.23.129
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/demo.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 33234
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /demo.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /demo.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /demo.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1648028605.456
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1648028605
```

here also [QUERY_STRING] => is empty

but in another demo server

```
[QUERY_STRING] => id=3
```

May i know the reason why main server not showing query_string?

```
Application Version - CI 3
PHP version - 5.6
```

Also am using AWS centos server

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the query string.

```
$this->config->set_item('enable_query_strings', TRUE);
```

A simple way to achieve this is by parsing the server query string like so.

```
$get_data = array();

parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $get_data);
```

This will leave you with a very insecure array full of data, so you should use CI's security class to make it more secure; so like;

```
$get_data = $this->security->xss_clean($get_data);
```